# Playwright - Navigating all API requests to be http based instead of https

Tags: http, browser, playwright

I'm creating a headless browser instance from inside my k8s cluster.
When trying to access my api I need to use http instead of https, as it's inside the cluster.
I've tried:

```
await page.route('**', (route) => {
  const url = route.request().url();

  // Check if the request is to my api
  if (url.startsWith('https://my.api.com')) {
    const newUrl = url.replace(/^https:/, 'http:');

    // Modify the request URL
    route.continue({ url: newUrl });
  } else {
    route.continue();
  }
});
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
error: route.continue: New URL must have same protocol as overridden URL
```

How can I fix it? also tried adding this stuff, without success:

```
args: ['--ignore-certificate-errors']
ignoreHTTPSErrors: true
```

Comment: https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-apirequestcontext