# Mixed Content in headless browser HTTP

Tags: http, chromium, playwright, same-origin-policy

I'm using Playwright to access my website, and would like to make all requests http instead of http, as I have A reverse proxy inside my pod which translates the hostname to localhost.

When trying to fetch my api in headless browser I'm getting this error:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://api.myapi.dev/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'http://api.myapi.dev/?email=test_user@company'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS
```

How to solve this? I must use http

Comment: "*would like to make all requests **http instead of http***" - did you mean **https instead of http**, or **http instead of https**? Either way, this doesn't really sound like a programming question, you might have better luck asking on [sf] instead.

Comment: The context here is unclear. Possibly related question asked by OP yesterday: [Playwright - Navigating all API requests to be http based instead of https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77820002/playwright-navigating-all-api-requests-to-be-http-based-instead-of-https). Consider taking a step back and explaining what you're trying to do, and providing a [mcve] of the site you're working with and your code. Thanks.